# Intermittent bug in the /search route when providing both tagged and nottagged parameters.

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

I'm getting the wrong number of results back from the [/search](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.9/help/method?method=search) route depending on what combination of values I provide for the `tagged` and `nottagged` parameters.

Examples:
http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/search?tagged=swing&nottagged=java

Here the response is reporting 149 total results, which is in agreement with what I'm currently seeing [on site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing+-java).  The page size returned is 30, but I'm only getting back 29 questions.

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/search?nottagged=php&tagged=curl

Here the total ([290](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curl+-php)) and page size (30) in the response are also correct, but I'm only getting back 28 questions.

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/search?tagged=curl&nottagged=perl

Here I'm only getting 27 questions returned in the first page of results when there are 894 in total.

#### Update:

It looks like there's been some progress (or this is mere coincidence) because when I run my tests again I get 29 questions in the result for the 3rd link instead of only 27.

Comment: Still no official answer on this one? Seems quite important to me!

Comment: bill - i show 30 for the 3rd link.

Comment: @Bill 30 to me on the 3rd

Comment: @code, @system, @Kevin: I'm now getting 30 on the 1st and 3rd links, but still only 29 on the second.  The `pagesize` value is correct (30), but only 29 questions are in the result.

Comment: @kevin - confirmed - 2nd link shows 29 results. o.t. - bill, only the first @ is honored, the rest are ignored.

Comment: @Bill - that'll teach me to count...  investigating.

Comment: @code: Thanks.  You'd think I would know how this system works by now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I think I've finally crushed this one.

This bloody bug has been an albatross.  Non-reproducible locally, intermittently reproducible on the database end... just gah, gah everywhere.

Comment: I had a feeling this one would be nasty when the test output started changing on its own.  Thanks for killing it.